# Performing a distributed search through spark-solr

Tags: apache-spark, solr, pyspark

I'm using [spark-solr](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr) in order to perform Solr queries. However, my searches don't work as they're supposed to because for some reason the requests being generated by spark prevent the searches from being distributed. I have discovered it by looking at the Solr logs where I saw that a `distrib=false` parameter is added to the sent requests. When executing the queries manually (not using spark) with `distrib=true` the results were fine.

I was trying to set the parameters sent by spark by changing the `"solr.params"` value in the `options` dictionary (I'm using [pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html)):

```
options = {
    "collection": "collection_name",
    "zkhost": "server:port",
    "solr.params": "distrib=true"
}

spark.read.format("solr").options(**options).load().show()
```

This change did not have any effect: I still see in the logs that a `distrib=false` parameter is being sent. Other parameters passed through the `"solr.params"` key (such as `fq=something`) do have an effect on the results. But it looks like spark insists on sending `distrib=false` no matter what I do.

How do I force a distributed search through spark-solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to configure the request handler to run distributed queries using an invariant. The invariant forces the `distrib` parameter to have a `true` value even if spark-solr is trying to change it in query time. Introducing the invariant can be done by adding the following lines under the definition of your request handler entry in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<lst name="invariants">
   <str name="distrib">true</str>
</lst>
```

While the introduction of the invariant is going to fix the problem, I think it's kind of a radical solution. This is because the solution involves hiding a behavior in which you overload the value of a parameter. By introducing the invariant you cannot decide to set `distrib` to `false`: even if your request explicitly does so, the value of `distrib` would still be `true`. This is too risky in my opinion and that's why I'm suggesting another solution which might be harder to implement but wouldn't suffer from that flaw.

The solution is to implement a query component which is going to force `distrib=true` only when receiving a `forceDistrib=true` flag as a parameter.

```
public class ForceDistribComponent extends SearchComponent {
   private static String FORCE_DISTRIB_PARAM = "forceDistrib";

   @Override
   public void prepare(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {
      ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams(rb.req.getParams());
      if (!params.getBool(FORCE_DISTRIB_PARAM, false)) return;
      params.set(CommonParams.DISTRIB, true);
      params.set(FORCE_DISTRIB_PARAM, false);
      rb.req.setParams(params);
   }
}
```

After building the component you can configure solr to use it by adding the component to `solrconfig.xml` and set your request handler to use it.

Adding the component to `solrconfig.xml` is done by adding the following entry to the `solrconfig.xml` file:

```
<searchComponent name="forceDistrib" class="ForceDistribComponent"/>
```

Configuring the request handler to use the `forceDistrib` component is done by adding it to the list of components under the request handler entry. It must be the first component in the list:

```
<arr name="components">
   <str>forceDistrib</str>
   <str>query</str>
   ...
</arr>
```

This solution, while more involved than simply introducing an invariant, is much safer.